# SQL invalid Identifier query

Tags: sql

I am getting an error that grandvisit is an invalid identifier, and I am unsure if I will get it with other identifiers either. Any light shed on this would be amazing. As I cannot see why it differents from others.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Nobody is going to sift through this mess.  Most likely a small mistake, but you need to shed some light on this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer the `alias` names in same `select` clause where it is generated.

```
SELECT Sum(aerosolvisit + hazvisit + hvvisit + hlopvisit
           + plvisit + miniloadvisit + aprvisit + apr2visit
           + aprawkvisit) AS grandvisit
```

To calculate `grandratio` you are using the below expression which uses the alias name `grandvisit`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Sum(grandtotal) = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN Sum(grandvisit) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE Sum(grandtotal) / Sum(grandvisit)
       END AS grandratio
```

You can use derived table to do this

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Sum(grandtotal) = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN Sum(grandvisit) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE Sum(grandtotal) / Sum(grandvisit)
       END AS grandratio 
From 
(
SELECT Sum(aerosolvisit + hazvisit + hvvisit + hlopvisit
           + plvisit + miniloadvisit + aprvisit + apr2visit
           + aprawkvisit) AS grandvisit 
 ...
) A
```

**Note :** You are using old style outer join's(`+=`). It is better to use `Right/Left` joins which is more readable

Comment: I have modified the original post with code I have edited following your comments. Thank you for your help as I can see where I've gone wrong. Not sure if I can nest sub queries as much as I have though.